# Compiler Error with function template specialization

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm using a class literal template that's basically defined as:

```
struct A {
public:
   const std::size_t size1, size2, size3;
}
```

I've made an instance of this with

```
constexpr A AInst = {1, 2, 1};
```

I then have a templated function that uses a size from the literal:

```
template<A a>
static void func(int arg1, double (*arg2)[a.size1]);
```

When I go to specialize this function I just get: "Internal compiler error." (using MSVC)

```
template<>
static void func<AInst>(int arg1, double (*arg2)[AInst.size1]){ /* implementation */}
```

Comment: "Internal compiler error" is a compiler bug, and you should report it. Otherwise, your code seems fine, except that you can't have `static` or any storage specifier for a specialization.

Comment: It looks like I get the same error even without static. I look into reporting it. Thank you!